# ng-disabled is not working in Firefox and chrome

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Currently I'm working on a project related to AngularJS. In there I need to disabled on

< a >

link. To do that I used **ng-disabled="true"**. This is not working in chrome and Firefox. But it works in IE. Someone suggested the change  link to a button. But in this project I can't convert those links to buttons.  Does anyone know how to do so?

Comment: ng-disabled="true" should do the job. But I'm not sure about what happening here. Which version of angular are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works well if you used AngularJS 1.1.5 version or higher

mine is v1.1.5, it also works well in all browsers.

Comment: I was using ng-disabled for <a> tag in my project and it's working fine

Comment: @BKM .  In All browser?

Comment: Yes IE, Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Which angular version you used?

Comment: A small change in your answer version 1.1.5 or higher

Comment: And that's for you dude, I will send the mark to you .. lol :p ;)

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS just maps the functionality of the `disabled` property of input elements with the ng-disabled directive.

This cannot work for `<a>` tags, since only input type elements have support for the `disabled` property.

If you really can not change the link to a button, your only option would be to add customized CSS and click handlers to those links.

Comment: @BKM the documentation lists usage only for inputs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Comment: They just shown an example with an input attribute there. But it work with the <a> tag also.

Comment: Then that is done with CSS tricks, not with disabled property, which does not include link elements as supported
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html